# TeamCity Batch Script File Size % Conflict

Tags: teamcity

I have the following as a custom script in a TeamCity build step:

```
for %%A in (*.err) do (
  if not %~zA==0 (
    echo."%%A" contains errors.
    set "retval=1"
  )
)
```

TeamCity log complains with "A was unexpected at this time.". Does anyone know what the work around might be?

---

Solution ended up being:

```
for %%%%A in (*.err) do (
      if not %%%%~zA==0 (
        echo."%%%%A" contains errors.
        set "retval=1"
      )
    )
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [official documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Defining+and+Using+Build+Parameters+in+Build+Configuration):

> If you want to prevent TeamCity from treating text in the percentage
>   signs as reference to a property you can escape them by using two
>   percentage signs. Every occurrence of "%%" in the values where
>   property references are supported will be replaced to "%" before
>   passing the value to the build. e.g. if you want to pass
>   "%Y%m%d%H%M%S" into the build, change it to "%%Y%%m%%d%%H%%M%%S"

So your code would look like:

```
for %%%%A in (*.err) do (
  if not %%%%~zA==0 (
    echo."%%%%A" contains errors.
    set "retval=1"
  )
)
```

Comment: Yep, I'm aware of the double %% becoming % and not being treated like a TC parameter. But, even with two %% on the 2nd line, it says the same error. This works fine outside of TC.

Comment: Did you converted double `%%` to quarter `%%%%`?

Comment: The solution was all lines requiring 4 %'s. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Even for `if not %%~zA==0` ? It should be `if not %%%%~zA==0`? Weird...

Comment: Yep, failed with just %%~zA.

Comment: Okay, will update my answer to reflect that. Thank you!